# CSS styling for width of a button to match its parent

Tags: css

I'm trying to add a `button` to a `div` so that the `width` of the `button` is same as the `width` of the `div`. As the sizes of `div`s are varying I can't give exact value in `px`. I've also tried `width=100%` but that didn't work.

Comment: We need the code to help you

Comment: Make the button `display: block`, and it should take up the entire width of the div.

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister Buttons are replaced elements. Even if you use `display: block`, their width will be calculated as for inline replaced elements, they won't grow to fill the containing block. See [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#block-replaced-width).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do like this for inline elements.

```css
div {
  width: 200px;

}
button {
  display: inline-block;   /* this shouldn't be needed on a button though */
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
<button>Button</button>
</div>
```

You can set the button to `display: block;` as well, though it will need the `width: 100%` in any case, but recommended is `display: inline-block;`.

*Side note:*

As Oriol pointed out, and in this case, it should be enough setting the width as the button element is a [replaced element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element)

Comment: Note the width of block, inline-block, and inline elements is calculated identically in case they are replaced like buttons. So `width: 100%` should be enough.

Comment: @Oriol Thanks, that is correct, updated my answer slightly to cover that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this below:

```
<div class="parent">
  <button>
     Button
  </button>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.parent{
   width:300px;
}
.parent button{
  width:100%;
}
```

Here is the live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/28v8zsc2/1/)

Comment: no need of jQuery unless you want to support legacy browsers

Comment: You are right, It was my mistake.